# gfxCardStatus for Windows

Tags: windows, amd-radeon, switchable-graphics

On Windows systems with switchable graphics (AMD Catalyst), how can I see which graphics card is currently in use?

Is there an alternative of the Mac's gfxCardStatus for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Run the AMD Catalyst Center, go to the "switchable Graphic Application settings", click on "Add application" and select the exe of the game and set it to high performance.

Now download the tool call [OpenHardwareMonitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) and add the AMD Radeon settings to the Gadget. if the GPU is not used you see a `-` for the GPU values:

[image]

If the GPU is used you see the data:

[image]